# I just installed Linux on a laptop without an OS, but it won't boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, installation, efi

I bought a new laptop for my sister which had no OS and I installed Ubuntu on it, however after the installation was complete it told me to restart the pc and I did, but it showed "Install Ubuntu" again and I clicked on it and it sad that Ubuntu was installed and asked me if I want to install it alongside Ubuntu, I also tried changing the boot order back to the HDD but then it said that no bootable OS was installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to remove the Ubuntu installation media DVD/USB before you reboot the laptop or else the laptop will try to boot from the installation media again instead of booting to the Ubuntu OS which is installed.

Another possibility is that you have accidentally installed the GRUB bootloader to the Ubuntu installer USB drive instead of to your laptop's hard drive, in which case you can repair it by booting from the Ubuntu installation media and repairing GRUB by opening the terminal and running this command:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

This will install grub to the MBR of the first hard drive to make it bootable.

Comment: I will now try to reinstall ubuntu instead of linux mint, if that doesn't work I shall apply the steps you provided, also I tried without usb and it says "no bootable device found"

Comment: Please read my long answer about how to prepare the Ubuntu USB installation media: https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/674454#674454. Ubuntu 16.04 is the latest Long Term Support (LTS) release of Ubuntu. The latest non-LTS release of Ubuntu which will be released in late October is Ubuntu 17.10, but the term of support for a non-LTS release is only 9 months instead of 5 years.

Comment: update yeah it seems that there is an error with grub since it is the same thing here

Comment: Read this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi/228069#228069 about the firmware (probably UEFI firmware) settings for installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi I tried repairing grub and it fails at the step 5 with EFI and says something doesn't exist.. :(

Comment: Please add the EFI message that says `something doesn't exist...` verbatim to your original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66990/discussion-between-karel-and-).